# How to pass arguments from text to macro in VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

When assigning a shape a macro, I am aware you can pass the shape as an argument like this:

```
Sub DoSomething(CShp as Shape)
    'code here using CShp as shape obj
End Sub
```

In PowerPoint you can also highlight text and assign it a macro when clicked. Would it be possible to pass the text that has been clicked as an argument? I've tried the following ideas to no avail:

```
Sub GetText(ShpText as Textframe)
'Nothing passes
End Sub

Sub GetText(ShpText as TextRange)
'Nothing passes
End Sub

Sub GetText(Shp as Shape)
Dim TxtRng as TextRange
Set TxtRng = Shp.TextFrame.TextRange
'Passes the whole text but not the clicked text only
End Sub
```

Many thanks

Comment: Sorry, there's nothing in the object model to pick up which word has been clicked on. You could do something roundabout by getting the cursor position and co-ordinating that with the shape position, but that would be so easy to break. What task are you trying to accomplish? There may be an easier way.

Comment: Is the word being clicked on a hyperlink?

Comment: Hello all. I am trying to create a non-activeX list of text whereby clicking an item within has its own function. The text is clicked on an action which runs the macro.